# How to deal with special characters in make command expansion?

Tags: python, makefile, escaping

Given the following python script:

```
print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")
```

and the following makefile

```
main:
        g++ main.cpp -I`python script.py`
```

Assuming `main.cpp` actually includes a file from `include_with\\[weird\\]characters`, this fails for me, with the compiler failing to find the included file.

However, if I use the [`shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) instead, it works. It also works if the path does not contain the weird characters. So for some reason, escaping seems to behave differently between backticks and the `shell`-function. Can someone explain why, and how I could modify the script so that it also works with backtick command expansion, if that is even possible?

I am using GNU Make 3.81 on Mac OS X 10.10.2 inside a `bash` shell. The script is run using Python 3.4.2.

Comment: Is that a representative path for this problem? Because the only case where you should get different output on the command line that I can tell is if you use `$(shell) and don't quote the variable expansion (so the backslashes are stripped by the shell). Is that the case that works?

Comment: When I use `$(shell python script.py)` in the makefile above, all other things being equal, it works. I don't understand what you mean by *don't quote the variable expansion*.

Comment: I mean `OUT := $(shell python script.py)` and then `g++ main.cpp -I$(OUT)` as opposed to `g++ main.cpp -I'$(OUT)` and yes, that's the one case (out of all possible quoting/etc. cases that differs and which allows the shell to remove the `\\` escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat BP.mk
VAR := $(shell python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")')

all:
        echo 'DIRECT := `python -c '\''print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'\''`'
        echo "DIRECT := `python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'`"
        echo DIRECT := `python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'`
        echo 'VAR := $(VAR)'
        echo "VAR := $(VAR)"
        echo VAR := $(VAR)
$ make -f BP.mk
echo 'DIRECT := `python -c '\''print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'\''`'
DIRECT := `python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'`
echo "DIRECT := `python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'`"
DIRECT := include_path_with\[weird\]characters
echo DIRECT := `python -c 'print("include_path_with\\[weird\\]characters")'`
DIRECT := include_path_with\[weird\]characters
echo 'VAR := include_path_with\[weird\]characters'
VAR := include_path_with\[weird\]characters
echo "VAR := include_path_with\[weird\]characters"
VAR := include_path_with\[weird\]characters
echo VAR := include_path_with\[weird\]characters
VAR := include_path_with[weird]characters
```

Notice how in all cases but the last that the backslashes persist into the output? That's the problem. You don't want them there. So what you want is not to print them at all and then quote the expansion so the shell doesn't then process the result at all.

So either

```
VAR2 := $(shell python -c 'print("include_path_with[weird]characters")')
g++ main.cpp -I'$(OUT)'
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -I"$$(python -c 'print("include_path_with[weird]characters")')"
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains it very well!

Comment: Strangely though, `pkg-config` does print escaped paths in this scenario. Is it not following best practice?

Comment: No, they are likely expecting that you can't quote the expansion since it may be multiple arguments.

Comment: I take that back actually. I'm not sure if that's a bug or not. What pkg-config package is doing that?

Comment: It's version 0.28 installed from homebrew.

Comment: The point is I am currently writing a tool that is supposed to be used in a similar way, and I am unsure how to deal with escaping now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what pkg-config *using* package has a path of that sort? And yes, I'm also unsure at this point but I think the answer is you lose either way. Spit out escaped characters and you won't match correctly but can output multiple words correctly (and the other words will work) Spit out unescaped characters and you aren't safe for multiple words. But I feel like I'm missing something here only I don't have time to think about it more at the moment.

Comment: Well, actually, I think the answer is you need to not spit out escapes and users need to not be naive about how the handle your output. That is they can't just spat it on the command line. They need to *read* it with a loop of some sort and use the words individually (or push them into an array and then use that). Or, but this doesn't help for everything, disable glob expansion with `set -f`.

Comment: This scenario happened in an automated integration test that generated these directory names. This has just brought up the issue, I would really like to be robust against it.

Comment: I think the choices are that you get to pick which set of users to support (and it looks like which set `pkg-config` has picked). You either get to support people splatting on the command line or those being careful about reading the output. Since you can't support both at the same time. I would be curious to bring this up to the pkg-config people and see what they think actually.